# Matplotlib.pyplot shows a get_data_path error message

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to run a little program for a school project, and my first line is :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

When I run this line I get :

```
File "/Users/quentin/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/JAUNE/Projet info RBM, CARRER, DUDUV/Projet info Bon 31 01.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 905, in <module>
    cbook._get_data_path("matplotlibrc"),
  File "/Users/quentin/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 480, in _get_data_path
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path'
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but nothing works.
Any idea ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please show the complete code where you are using it.

Comment: Have the same issue when using the plot() method of pandas dataframe